# How to display images in a listview using Volley?

Tags: android

We have a problem when we get images from database and want to display them in a listView with title and description

// We get first the image from database throw Json Object

```
map= new HashMap<String, Object>();

   String encoded = unProduit.getString("image");
   byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encoded, Base64.DEFAULT);
   Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, 
   decodedString.length);
   Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),decodedByte);
   map.put("img", d);
// to display in listeview

    SimpleAdapter monAdapter = new SimpleAdapter (Activity_Recherche_produit.this, tabProduits, R.layout.layout_produit_listview,
 new String[] {"img", "mnom", "mville","mdate" },
 new int[] {R.id.img, R.id.idnomprod, R.id.idville,R.id.iddate});

But when we set image to imageView , it works
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Volley you retrieve your image and why not title and description

You need a layout (let's call it layoutImage) to represent an item in your list, so your layout should have an imageview for your image, a textview for title and a textview for description

My advice is to create an adapter

```
ImageListAdapter imageListAdapter = new ImageListAdapter(layoutImage, ...)
```

with a subClass ImageListAdapter of ArrayAdapter where you described the UI

```
public class ImageListAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
    @Override
    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { ...
    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileimage);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
    ... }
}
```

and to associate your list of images

```
imageListAdapter.addall(listImages)
```

Of course a ListView is required :

```
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listviewimages);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can even specify what occurs when selecting an image

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ...
        }
    });
```